# Link to filtered html using JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to link to a filtered list that is organised via JavaScript or Jquery, as shown below. Is it possible to do this with JavaScript or Jquery alone or would I need to use a server side language to achieve this.

Can I grab the addressing that they came in from and parse that data through the JS?

For example www.mysite.com/#data-filter-a

```
<button class="active btn" data-filter="box">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="a">Show A</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="b">Show B</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="c">Show C</button>
<button class="btn" data-filter="d">Show D</button>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="box a b">A &amp; B</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c a">C &amp A</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
</div>



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
.spacer {
  clear: both;
  height: 20px;
}

var $boxs = $("#parent > .box");
var $btns = $(".btn").on("click", function() {

  var active = 
    $btns.removeClass("active")
      .filter(this)
      .addClass("active")
      .data("filter");

  $boxs
    .hide()
    .filter( "." + active )
    .fadeIn(450);

});
```

http://codepen.io/simeydotme/pen/ewKBr

Answer (score 1):

All you want is getting the hash part of the URL and triggering the click handler of matching button on page load:

```
var res = window.location.hash.match(/data-filter-(\w+)/);

if ( res ) {
    $btns.filter(function() {
       return $(this).data('filter') === res[1];
    }).click();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work and I have no errors in the console. Hmm...
Thanks for the pointer in the window.location.hash though. It's my step in the right direction

Comment: There are no errors which is annoying as I can't seem to work out why it won't work.

Comment: Try clearing the cache. Also make sure that you have put the code after your original code. What does `console.log(res)` show?

Comment: Yeah I did... I tried this  
if ( window.location.hash ) {
    $(window.location.hash).click();
}  
 and it worked... although this is probably messy right. As in could lead to problems

Comment: This was by adding an id to the buttons too. But could this mean people could link into your page incorrectly and have them click another id?

Comment: @databot Well, that's true, your current solution selects an element that has the matching id, if it has a click handler then the handler of that element is executed otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: It's probably good enough. But how would I check it only matches my buttons and only execute when this is correct.
Thanks so much for such a great resource. You've been a great help.

Comment: @databot you are very welcome! I'm glad I could help! If you want select just those button elements, use `button` in your selector: `$('button' + window.location.hash)` . The point is using a more specific selector.

Comment: Yeah do you mean creating a piece of code that is just perfect?   (As in without someone - unlikely that they would - being able to add a hash at the end of my link and hyperlinking to then click a part I wouldn't want?)
Thank you again! Hope you get to that 100k mark soon. Not far now.

Comment: @databot You are welcome! Thanks for mentioning this. I highly appreciate it.